# Any Detailed Documentation On The New Geth v1.4.0 JSON-RPC Protocol Revisions Yet?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I read that geth v1.4.0 had a complete overhaul related to the JSON-RPC protocol. Now that v1.4.0 is nearly a stable release, I am curious to find out if any of these latest revisions have been documented anywhere yet for developers to use in their applications?

I have resumed building an app which I started last summer (devoting to it full time 5 days per week starting May 2nd until a stable release), which relies almost completely on the geth JSON-RPC protocol...so I'm keen to understanding the latest / greatest features fully as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've indeed given our RPC interface a massive overhaul, however the parts which have seen significant changes are internal ones. The *actual* [JSON-RPC specification](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) itself has not changed at all (i.e. web3's interface). We (go-ethereum) do not alone drive the specification for web3 and we require consensus between implementations (e.g. C++, Python, Java, Rust).

However our own RPC interface, which isn't included in web3, did change. We've removed and added functionality and cleaned up the mess that was included in some of the [namespaces](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis). At the moment `geth` supports the following transport layers:

- HTTP
- IPC (unix domain socket, Win named pipe)
- IPC (in memory)
- WS

In addition to changing and cleaning up the namespaces we've [fully documented](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) the go-ethereum RPC and added JavaScript examples where appropriate. All methods are available by default over IPC and can be turned on for HTTP using the `--rpcapi` CLI flag.